# How does Elasticsearch implement the following SQL statement

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I have the following SQL statement, I want to use ES7.13 implementation, please ask how I should write the code.

```sql
SELECT created_at from customer WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') = '06'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about querying specific month in date. So the solution is to use script

```
POST /customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filter" : {
      "script" : {
        "script" : {
          "source": "doc['created_at'].value.getMonthValue() == 6",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Es7.13 uses the following code

```
POST /customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": "doc['created_at'].value.getMonthValue() == 6",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```